# ¿Qué significa "habida cuenta"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, locuciones

¿Qué significa "habida cuenta" en esta oración? Creo que es igual a "dado", pero sólo por el contexto. Nunca he visto «haber» utilizado así.

> Comencé a caminar en dirección al salón con alguna dificultad, **habida cuenta** de que no tocaba el suelo.

What does *habida cuenta* mean in this sentence? I would translate it as *dado* ("given"), but only based on the context. I've never seen *haber* used like this.

Comment: It's a fixed phrase. It can be translated as **given that.**

Comment: @CarlosArturoSerrano can you put that as an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an expression that means «teniendo en cuenta»:

> [**habida cuenta de** algo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BaAYElz)
>
> 1. loc. verb. Teniéndolo en cuenta, a la vista de ello.

Your translation as «dado» is also valid.

Answer (score 3):

Como han dicho otros, la fórmula "habida cuenta de" equivale a "teniendo en cuenta que", o simplemente "dado que". Es un uso de "haber" como equivalente a "tener", y por eso pensaba que esta expresión vendría de antiguo habida cuenta (guiño) de que dicha equiparación hace tiempo que quedó obsoleta.

Sin embargo, buscando casos tanto en el CORDE como en la hemeroteca, me encuentro con que el caso más antiguo es de 1845. Así que me imaginé que la expresión se crearía como una variación de otras construcciones similares, y ahí ya sí que di con expresiones parecidas de mucho más atrás en el tiempo (negritas mías):

> *Pero porque esto podia ocasionar, que los Indios por quedarse ociosos, pidiesen excesivos jornales, y asi se hiciese falta en los servicios públicos, se mandó luego por otra cédula de la misma data, y por otra de dos de Diciembre de 1563, que los Magistrados, y Reales Audiencias los tasen, **habida consideracion** de los tiempos, Provincias, caminos, y trabajo de los ministerios en que se havian de ocupar; pero esto de tal manera, que tódo se mirase por el bien de los Indios.*
>
> Juan de Solórzano y Pereira, "Política indiana", 1648 (España).

Y también:

> *[...] e pidió al dicho señor teniente que **habida información** dello le mandase abrir, leer y publicar el dicho testamento, para que se guardase y cumpliese según y como en él se contenía; [...]*
>
> Anónimo, "Cláusula del testamento que hizo el obispo de Chiapa don fray Bartolomé de las Casas", 1566 (España).

Si te fijas, en ambos casos se podrían sustituir las expresiones en negrita por "habida cuenta". Por tanto podríamos afirmar que sí, es una expresión que viene de antiguo, manteniendo la estructura arcaica de "habida + sustantivo" pero con una pequeña variante.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fixed phrase. It can be translated as **given that**.